# tex studio loses parts of structure view when changing document class to koma-script

Tags: texstudio

Thanks to the hint by @Lemgo answer below, I was able to make a very small MWE which shows this problem. Making a `table` end one `subsection` caused the following `section` to be removed from the structure !  This only happens when the `documentclass` is `scrartcl`. Here is the MWE and small movie showing how this happens

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}% 
%article
%scrartcl

\begin{document}
\section{A}
text

\subsection{B}
text
\begin{tabular}[c]{cc}
a&b
\end{tabular}

\section{C}
text    
\end{document}
```

Image:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is also small movie

[image]

---

**Original question kept for reference**

I have been having such problems with texstudio `Structure` view, which shows the document structure, which I depend on very much to be able to navigate large document with many sections and subsections.

I found out, for some strange reason, TexStudio does not like koma-script class.

In the video below, when I change the document class to `scrartcl` from `article` and reopen texstudio, it losses most of the structure and displays small part of the document tree.

I made sure I clean all Auxillary files also before each time, but this has no effect. Even if I compile, it still do not show the structure if document class is koma-script type.

Any one else had this problem and can even suggest a fix for it?  Here is small video showing the problem. I open and close texstudio and one can see the structure shows up fully only when the document class is `article`. Why?

Notice the document class and the structure on the left panel and how the structure is lost only when document class is changed. I also noticed that I had to close TexStudio and reopen it to see the full structure after changing document class to `article`. Even compiling does not help. Had to close and reopen to get the full structure back. It seems TeXStudio only build the structure initially when it open the document.

This problem seems to happen when the document becomes large. On small document, it seems to work ok. And so far, I have not been to find what can causes this for large document.

Is there a trick to tell tex studio to rebuild the structure explicitly? May be if there is such option I could try it each time. Is there a log file to look at that can show any warnings or errors by TeXStudio?

[image]

Windows 7, 64 bit, Tex studio 2.11.0

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Isn't that something that should be reported directly to Tim?

Comment: @Johannes_B I do not know how to report these things to TeXStudio. The TeXStudio forum requires a sign-in and I have not been able to get an account. It uses [SourceForge site](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907839) which needs an account set up to post questions. I saw Texstudio tag here, so I assume TexStudio questions are allowed. WHen I clicked on send message, it said I must be logged in. But source forge giving hard time to make account and I am not getting any reply from it.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem today with parts of my structure missing (scrartcl as well). Seems like only sections which come after some non-text-parts (like figures, listings, tables, etc.) are affected.
So for example, if a section ends with a figure the following section is missing in the structure tree...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1840/) in 2.11.0 and already fixed.

You may try the most recent development snapshot from
https://sourceforge.net/projects/texstudio/files/texstudio/TeXstudio%20development/ or wait for the next release.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to download this if someone has no account at sourceforge? It asks for a login. I can't login any more using my old account.

Comment: Sorry, the link was wrong -> now fixed.